# Prevent nav item to a new line when reduce page width

Tags: html, css

Hi Guys I have create a react app with react-bootstrap and I am creating a header navigation bar. I have one nav brand and two nav items. The right-hand nav item is an input-group. The problem is the input-group goes to a new line when reduce the width of the page and I just want the input group stay the same line when resize.

Here is my code:
https://repl.it/repls/IrresponsibleCuddlyConversions#index.html

Any Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the working code?

Comment: This is the link to the working code. 
  https://repl.it/repls/IrresponsibleCuddlyConversions#index.html

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: @AndyHoffman Please ask users to post the code example in their question, not a link to a site. This question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site linked to is inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

**Setting the min-width and max-width values in css** is the easiest way to prevent the nav elements from stacking one below the other when screen width is changed.

**Here is the updated file with min-width and max-width specified:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary" 
      style="min-width: 480px;">
    <div class="navbar-brand ml-3">
            <button>btn</button>
    </div>

    <div class='nav-item'>
        <h3 class='d-sm-block text-nowrap' style="max-width: 200px;">PROJECT TITLE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group ml-2 nav-item" style="width: 150px; max-width: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0px;">
        <input class="form-control"
               type="search"
               placeholder="New Stuff..."/>
        <span class='input-group-btn'>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
            ...
        </button>
               </span>
    </div>
</nav>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```